# Aborted connection error in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

If the client closes an established connection that it has made with the *flask* server, I get the following error in the terminal:

```
[Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

It seems when *flask* tries to write in the closed stream, it faces errors and hence will complain.
It seemed like a warning or so as the application does not quit after printing the error, but the problem is that my server will stop serving other requests despite being alive in the system.

I have read similar questions but they did not help. How can I prevent this issue? I use both Windows and Linux operating systems.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @Gator_Python Yes, I am.

Comment: Try running with administrator privileges - These are likely required to open a socket on the port you're using.

Comment: @Gator_Python I am developing the service on Windows, but the deployment environment uses Linux.

Comment: Are you having this problem on your Linux system as well? I believe the problem is that your system has a policy that either requires admin rights to open the port or restricts the port by policy altogether. Check your firewall settings if running as an admin doesn't work.

Comment: @Gator_Python I'm trying what you instructed, will let you know about the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125627/discussion-between-ahmad-siavashi-and-gator-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this problem is, as we previously discussed, insufficient permissions to perform the network operation. The remedy to the problem was to run the process as an administrator and/or to modify the system policy to allow connections on the restricted port.